# "Invalid string or buffer length" when i copy over more than 106 values?

Tags: string, oracle, ms-access, buffer

I'm trying to copy an Access database over to Oracle SQL. It works up top the point that it has to copy over more than 106 values. (The problematic table contains over 1000 values)

I've used both the jdbc:odbc bridge drivers and the dedicated MS driver. I'm running a 64 bit Oracle Database (11g), 64 bit windows 7 and 64 bit jdk.

Here is a picture of my Access database fields and their datatypes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEbKy.jpg

Here is the code I use to copy over the values. (Keep in mind that the same method works perfectly with tables with less than 100 values)

Also they are out of order because someone had previously suggested that i put them in order of datatype, but this didn't help.

```
public static void copyCriminalTable()
{
    PreparedStatement updateCourtOrderTable  = null;

    //Set up "insert" string
    String insertString = "INSERT INTO criminal "
            + "(id, firstname, lastname, streetaddress, suburb, postcode, state, email, phonenumber, dob, weight, height, licencenumber) "
            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    String MSAccessQuery = "SELECT * FROM criminal";

    try
    {
        //create a query object for MSAccess
        dbmsMSAccess.DBMSStatement = dbmsMSAccess.DBMSConnection.createStatement();
        //Query the MSAccess database for extraction
        dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet = dbmsMSAccess.DBMSStatement.executeQuery(MSAccessQuery);
        //make query object for Oracle
        dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleStatement = dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleConnection.createStatement();

        //dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleStatement.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE criminal");

        dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

        updateCourtOrderTable = dbmsOracle.DBMSOracleConnection.prepareStatement(insertString);

        while(dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.next())
        {

            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(13, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("licencenumber") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(1, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("ID") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(2, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("firstname") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(3, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("lastname") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(4, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("streetaddress") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(5, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("suburb") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(6, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("postcode") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(7, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("state") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(8, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("email") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(9, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("phonenumber") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setDate(10, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getDate("dob") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(11, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("weight") );
            updateCourtOrderTable.setString(12, dbmsMSAccess.DBMSResultSet.getString("height") );


            updateCourtOrderTable.executeUpdate();

            //set delay
            //Thread.sleep(20);

        }

        System.out.println("Criminal: ACCESS DATA COPIED TO ORACLE");

    }
    catch(Exception X)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Criminal TABLE");
        X.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

The Error I get is:

```
ERROR - Criminal TABLE
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(JdbcOdbc.java:3906)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5697)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:353)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:410)
    at DBMSISYS254.DBMSMain.copyCriminalTable(DBMSMain.java:178)
    at DBMSISYS254.DBMSMain.copyAllTables(DBMSMain.java:58)
    at DBMSISYS254.DBMSMain.main(DBMSMain.java:44)
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions.

EDIT: This method also works perfectly if I limit the while loop to running less than 100 times.

Comment: is it possible that one of the columns of the 106'th row you are trying to insert is bigger then what you defined in oracle ?

Comment: ...or, similar to what @haki suggested, could a string field in the 106th (or 107th) row in the Access table contain either a zero-length string or a `Null` value?

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the suggestions =D I checked everything  and the only solution that i could come up with was that the odbc driver doesn't work very well on 64 bit systems. 

I don't know if it's the optimal solution, but just installed win7 on a VM as well as access(32 bit) and the oracle database. 

Everything works perfectly and i didn't change a line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, after scouring through the internet, that the odbc driver doesn't like 64 bit systems.

What I then did was:

Install windows 7(32 bit), Access(32bit) and Oracle Database 11g(32bit) on a virtual machine.

I linked the access(mdb) file using 'Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)'.

I then ran the program as usual (linking to localhost oracle database) and it all worked perfectly.

I don't know if this solution was optimal, but it seemed to solve every single problem i once had.

Thanks to everyone who posted suggestions!

Comment: Just to clarify: It was the *Oracle* ODBC driver that was giving you trouble in a 64-bit environment, was it?